# Electron window shows a screenshot of the screen

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron

So I have an electron app named `main.js` which I start with `npm start`. I've set the start script in package.json to `electron main.js` and have also tried `electron .`. When running `npm start`, everything starts without any errors but the electron window only shows a snapshot of what was on the screen when I started it. I've tried refreshing it but nothing seems to work. Here is how it looks: 
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPO9l.png)
It should view `localhost:3001` but it doesn't. I've also tried to run `electron .` directly in the terminal but that gives me `electron: command not found`. When running `./node_modules/electron/dist/electron .` it starts as it should but the same problem occurs. Here is `main.js`:

```
const electron = require('electron');
const app = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;
const core = require('./app');

let mainWindow

function createWindow() {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: { webSecurity: false },
        nodeIntegration: false,
    })

    mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:3001');

    // mainWindow.setFullScreen(true)

    // mainWindow.setMenu(null);

    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

    mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
        mainWindow = null
    })

    console.log('Electron window ready')
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
    app.quit()
})

core.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you didn't install Electron globally, for that you need to run `npm install -g Electron`

Replace `mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:3001');` With:

```
mainWindow.loadURL(
  url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, "index.html"),
    protocol: "file:",
    slashes: true
  })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not shared your `package.json` file, but I will guess you did not run `npm install --save electron` in your terminal.

Also, instead of:

```
const electron = require('electron');
const app = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;
```

you want to write it like so:

```
const electron = require('electron');
const { app, BrowserWindow } = electron;
```

I would review ES6 destructuring and unless you did not share the code with us, you should start your electron project by assuring that the `app` object is ready and loading your file like so:

```
let mainWindow;

app.on('ready', () => {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({});
  mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/main.html`);
});
```

You will notice I declared an empty `mainWindow` variable to take care of any scoping issues you may have as you may have to use `mainWindow` in other functions as well.